# join 2 stored procedures in another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures for instanse test1 and test2 and both use the same parameter X.

X is part of an if statement in both these stored procedures, basically it tells the the procedure which select statement to pick. (this shouldn't matter as it's a parameter but i'm not sure)

I want test1 and test2 to be joined by column name, as they will both have the column name, and i want them linked side by side not one underneath the other, is this possible and how

Basically, i want to join these 2 stored procedures in another stored procedure that my asp.net program will call.

this is stored procedure (sp_current)

```
@mode varchar(20)




AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @Booked Int
Set @Booked = CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year,  (year( getdate() )) - Year(getdate() + 1),                   
                DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 1) ) )

 If @mode = 'Sales'
      Select
           Division,
           SDESCR,
           DYYYY,

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then NetAmount End) currentNetSales,       
       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS currentPAX        



      From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails
      Where  DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))
      Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division           
      Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY

else if @mode = 'netsales'

Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  


       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then NetAmount End) currentNetSales,        


       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS currentPAX      



From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY 

Else if @mode = 'Inssales'

Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then InsAmount End) currentInsSales,        

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS currentPAX        

From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY 

Else if @mode = 'CXsales'
Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then CancelRevenue End) currentCXSales,        


       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS currentPAX        


From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY 

Else if @mode = 'othersales'
Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  

   Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then OtherAmount End) currentOtherSales,        
       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS currentPAX        



From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY 

Else if @mode = 'cxvalue'
Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then CXVALUE End) currentCXValue,
       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS currentPAX        



From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY
```

and 
This is sp_compare

```
@mode varchar(20),
@YearToGet int



AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @Booked Int
Set @Booked = CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, @YearToGet - Year(getdate() + 1),                   
                DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 1) ) )

 If @mode = 'Sales'
      Select
           Division,
           SDESCR,
           DYYYY,

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then NetAmount End) ASofNetSales,        
       SUM(NetAmount) AS YENetSales,

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS ASofPAX,        
       SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX


      From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails
      Where  DYYYY = @YearToGet
      Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division           
      Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY

else if @mode = 'netsales'

Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  


       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then NetAmount End) ASofNetSales,        
       SUM(NetAmount) AS YENetSales,

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS ASofPAX,        
       SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX


From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = @YearToGet
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY 

Else if @mode = 'Inssales'

Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  

      Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then InsAmount End) ASofInsSales,        
       SUM(InsAmount)  AS YEInsSales, 

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS ASofPAX,        
       SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX

From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = @YearToGet
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY 

Else if @mode = 'CXsales'
Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  

      Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then CancelRevenue End) ASofCXSales,        
       SUM(CancelRevenue) AS YECXSales, 


       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS ASofPAX,        
       SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX

From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = @YearToGet
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY 

Else if @mode = 'othersales'
Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  

   Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then OtherAmount End) ASofOtherSales,        
       SUM(OtherAmount) AS YEOtherSales,

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS ASofPAX,        
       SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX


From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = @YearToGet
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY 

Else if @mode = 'cxvalue'
Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then CXVALUE End) ASofCXValue,
       SUM(CXVALUE) AS YECXValue,


       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS ASofPAX,        
       SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX


From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = @YearToGet
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY
```

I either want to make it one procedure or somehow join them side by side in a seperate procedure

Comment: Make them table valued functions rather than stored procedures then you can join on them. Might be quite inefficient though especially as they both appear to be using the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vage. I guess that both procedures returna result set and you want to return a join of those result sets.

You can define temporary tables or table variables and use

```
INSERT INTO table_1 exec sp_1 ...
INSERT INTO table_2 exec sp_2 ...
```

Than you can select from a join from those 2 temporary objects.

EDIT:
Not knowing the data-types let me try something like

```
create table #tmp1 (
  Division varchar(50),
  SDESCR varchar850),
  DYYYY varchar(5),
  currentNetSales money,
  currentPax money
)

create table #tmp2 (
  Division varchar(50),
  SDESCR varchar(50),
  DYYYY varchar(5),
  ASofNetSales money,        
  YENetSales money,
  ASofPAX money,        
  YEPAX money
)

 INSERT INTO #tmp1 exec sp_current ('Sales')
 INSERT INTO #tmp2 exec sp_compare ('Sales', 2009)

select t1.Division,
 isnull(t1.SDESCR, t2.SDESCR) SDESCR,
 isnull(t1.DYYYY, t2.DYYYY) DYYYY,
 t1.currentNetSales,
 t1.currentPax,
 t2.ASofNetSales money,        
 t2.YENetSales money,
 t2.ASofPAX money,        
 t2.YEPAX money
from #tmp1 t1
  full outer join #tmp2 t2 on t1.Division = t2.Division and t1.SDESCR = t2.SDESCR
 Order By Division, SDESCR
```

Comment: Ill add some more to my question

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - given bernd_k's answer, it might be more worth adding an example, e.g. show some possible samples "these are the rows from sp1", "these are the rows from sp2", "this is what I want to return as a result"

Comment: yeah i think instead of doing them in seperate procedures, i am going to try and put them in one giant one if you could help that would be great. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605912/stored-procedure-issue-has-to-do-with-my-where-clause-and-if-statement