# stored procedure issue, has to do with my where clause and if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

right now my stored procedure is returning 2 different result sets one for @booked and the other for @booked1

if you look closely my query is doing the same thing for each @booked and @booked but one is for a user selected year and the other for the current year.

I don't want two different result sets, i want to join the selected year and the current year side by side by SDESCR(which is a column that they have in common)

another hurdle i am facing is i am use @mode to decide whether the user wants netsales, sales... so on.

I know i need sometype of join but, it isnt working because i have a where statement that says where dyyyy= @yeartoget

which won't allow the current year data to work

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test1]
@mode varchar(20),
@YearToGet int



AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @Booked Int
Set @Booked = CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, @YearToGet - Year(getdate() + 1),                   
                DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 1) ) )

Declare @Booked1 Int
Set @Booked1 = CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year,  (year( getdate() )) - Year(getdate() + 1),                   
                DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 1) ) )


 If @mode = 'Sales'
      Select
           Division,
           SDESCR,
           DYYYY,

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then NetAmount End) ASofNetSales,        
       SUM(NetAmount) AS YENetSales,

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS ASofPAX,        
       SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX


      From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails
      Where  DYYYY = @YearToGet
      Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division           
      Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY

else if @mode = 'netsales'

Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  


       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then NetAmount End) ASofNetSales,        
       SUM(NetAmount) AS YENetSales,

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS ASofPAX,        
       SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX


From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = @YearToGet
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY 


If @mode = 'Sales'
      Select
           Division,
           SDESCR,
           DYYYY,

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked1 Then NetAmount End) currentNetSales,       
       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked1 Then PARTY End) AS currentPAX        



      From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails
      Where  DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))
      Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division           
      Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY

else if @mode = 'netsales'

Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  


       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked1 Then NetAmount End) currentNetSales,        


       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked1 Then PARTY End) AS currentPAX      



From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY 

Else if @mode = 'Inssales'

Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY,  

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked1 Then InsAmount End) currentInsSales,        

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked1 Then PARTY End) AS currentPAX        

From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY
```

Comment: My main suggestion: make this separate stored procs, one for each "mode" - don't pack all those different select into a single stored proc....

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding why assign @booked with SELECT CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, @YearToGet - Year(getdate() + 1),                   
                DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 1) ) ). If I choose 2011 as @YearToGet, the result is 40546. Is that your intended result?, or should it be a year?

Comment: yeah whoever developed our databases wanted to make life hard and uses integers as dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy approach to have the side by side results is to use sub-queries in side the From

Note: this is just for mode = Sales

```
SELECT
           b.Division,
           b.SDESCR,
           b.DYYYY,
           b.YENetSales,
           b.YEPAX
           b1.Division,
           b1.SDESCR,
           b1.DYYYY,
           b1.currentNetSales,
           b1.currentPAX     

FROM
(Select
       Division,
       SDESCR,
       DYYYY,

   Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then NetAmount End) ASofNetSales,        
   SUM(NetAmount) AS YENetSales,

   Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS ASofPAX,        
   SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX


  From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails
  Where  DYYYY = @YearToGet
  Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division         
) b

  FULL OUTER JOIN 
  (
Select
       Division,
       SDESCR,
       DYYYY,

   Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked1 Then NetAmount End) currentNetSales,       
   Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked1 Then PARTY End) AS currentPAX     
  From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails
  Where  DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))
  Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division  ) b1
  ON b.divsion = b1.divsion
     and
     b.SDESCR = b1.SDESCR   --might not be required

 Order By b.Division, b.SDESCR, b.DYYYY
```

The other approach is to change your where clause to include both @booked and @booked1 and then do a case statement on each field

Comment: would this work even with the if statement, or do cte not work with if statements

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test1, Line 61
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test1, Line 74
Incorrect syntax near 'b1'.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts. Actually this isn't a CTE this is standard SQL subqueries. CTEs  would actually make it eaiser.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts. Ok I updated my answer for the Order By Problem

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test1, Line 74
Invalid column name 'divsion'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test1, Line 74
Invalid column name 'divsion'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test1, Line 42
Invalid column name 'YENetSales'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test1, Line 43
Invalid column name 'YEPAX'.

Comment: i hate SPs, cant live with them and cant live without them

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I missed that the field aliases on B1 where different than B

Comment: @Conrad, I stand corrected - no temp tables needed.  I should have read the queries more carefully.  (+1)

Comment: Might want to give the duplicate field names different aliases though.